# jquery disable auto scroll dragging element in body

Tags: jquery

following exactly the example from
[getting started](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

when the div goes outside the window the document scrool this is ok

I tried to initialize with this option
from  api documentation

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({scroll:false});
  } );
```

The div still scroll the document.
Is it a jquery bug ?

I thankyou for any suggestion but I don't like to use workaround such as put container to wrap the area.
The  user  must be able to move the div without scrolling the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
$( window ).mousemove(function( event ) {
  var $el = $('#draggable');
  var $window=$( window ).height();
  var $bottom = $el.position().top + 100 ;
  var $top = $window - 100;
  if ($bottom > $window ){
    $('#draggable').css({ top: $top });
  }

});
```

jsfiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mr_seven/bcrx2gnj/32/

Comment: thanks for the hint, I added limit for top  and left right
thiugh I think it is a jquery bug